# Media Request Analytics Failed

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I got the following error in the log files of my upgraded site:

```
2628 2016:12:09 13:07:13 ERROR Media request analytics failed
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String message)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.OnMediaRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Any ideas what is the cause of this?

Comment: Is this error in any way related to [**Experience Analytics**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing__reporting/analytics/experience_analytics_overview)? Asking because of the tag.

Comment: A couple more things. 1) What's your Sitecore version? 2) Try to [**disable robot detection**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/robot_detection/configure_the_robot_detection_component#_Disabling_robot_detection) to see if that is the root of the issue.

Comment: Where do you see this error? CM? CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into the same issue on our CM server (Sitecore 8.1 Update 3, robot detection disabled) and found we had to do the following as detailed on a different documentation page https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/disable_robot_detection_on_a_content_management_server

Change:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

to

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```