# How to disable analytics for media request analytics failed Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: xdb, media-library

Basically, I disabled xDB fully on web site, 
but I still see errors from Analytics

```
ERROR Media request analytics failed

Exception:
  System.InvalidOperationException Message: Tracker.Current is not initialized 

Source: Sitecore.Analytics
  at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args) at (Object , Object[] )
  at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
  at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
  at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
  at Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.StartTracking()
  at Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.OnMediaRequest(Objec sender, EventArgs args)
```

How to disable analytics for media requests?

Comment: This might help: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/media-request-analytics-failed

Comment: 1) Which version of Sitecore? 2) How exactly did you disable xDB? 3) In your `ShowConfig.aspx`, check the value of `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled`. It needs to be set to `false`.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko it was done 100% it is only one issue with images

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @BenGolden  sitecore 8.2 with latest SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through code that is inside of `MediaRequestSessionModule` which is inherited from `Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule`

The problem is I need to keep `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` on, but `Xdb` off. Regarding code inside of `MediaRequestSessionModule` the best way is just to disable `OnMediaRequest`:

```
 <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="media:request">
        <handler method="OnMediaRequest">
          <patch:delete />
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Thanks. We needed `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` turned on as well to be able to use/track some personalization stuff but we don't need all of xDB for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` setting to `false`. The first thing the `OnMediaRequest` method does is check that setting and exit if it is `false`. You could not get the stack trace shown if that setting were `false`. Check the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page to confirm the setting after all config patches have been merged in.